# Java sockets losing data: BufferedReader

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, bufferedreader, java-io

I'm having the following problem in java: I am developing and app using `java.net.Socket`. It looks like that: There is a server with a thread which accepts and adds new client, and another thread which reads data from sockets and does "something" with it. Next to it there are clients. Client has data reader thread as well as a separate thread. I send the data as simple as:

```
socket.getOutputStream().write((content+"\n").getBytes());
```

on the client side and read it on the server like:

```
try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    String received;
    while(true) {
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            received = reader.readLine();
            if(received == null) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("SERVER " + received);
            increaseReceivedCounter(1);
        } catch(SocketException e) {
            break;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    System.out.println("SERVER RECEIVED "+ getReceivedCounter() + " MESSAGES!");
}
```

Now I just set the client to send some amount of messages like this:

```
try {
    int n = 1000;
    System.out.println("sending "+ n +" messages to " + client);
    for(int i=0 ; i<n ; ++i) {
        socket.getOutputStream().write((content+"\n").getBytes());
    }
    System.out.println("done sending " + n + " messages");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The problem is that not all of the messages are transferred to a server. I have been looking for some solution for this but didn't manage to achieve 100% reliability. Is it even possible? I also tried with `read` instead of `readLine` but the result is the same: sometimes even 90% data loss. I think while server is working on the received data it ignores incoming packets and they're just lost.

### Edit

`Socket`s initializations:

```
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(Server.PORT);//PORT = 9876, whatever
```

for the data reader on server side:

```
socket = serverSocket.accept();
```

on the client:

```
socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", Server.PORT)
```

Comment: How do you initialize the sockets? Also, why are you creating a new reader with every iteration in the while loop?

Comment: Are you seeing errors in the logs? Your server-side snippet implies that you silently ignore any `SocketException`s; maybe log these properly, as well?

Comment: I don't silently ignore them because(from Eclipse): `The exception SocketException is already caught by the alternative IOException` and there are no `SocketException`s. That `reader` initialization in loop is a mistake, I deleted it but still it didn't change anything. `Socket` initialization in edit.

Comment: Maybe the client is closing the connection (in code not shown, after the sending `for` cycle) before the server manages to read all the messages?

Comment: How do you know that there are no `SocketException`s? If one was thrown, you'd catch it and ignore it, right? Try removing that `catch` block altogether.

Comment: Are you using any network based software like Wireshark ?

Comment: Maybe the client/server isn't sending the data to the server/client, try flushing the data on the `OutputStream` using the `flush` method after using `write`.

Comment: @LaVloZMerrill The `flush()` method of a socket output stream, or any other output stream that isn't buffered, does nothing. The problem is at the other end.

Comment: @EJP that's not always the true, because `OutputStreamReader` internals there's buffer (i already got some headaches with it because of buffering), and `Socket.OutputStream` is associated with OS implementation, maybe `OutputStream` send data to OS but OS buffer it for optimisation reasons, another thing, you can get a `BufferedOutputStream` from a method which return `OutputStream`, so always when you got some problems like that, try to flush the `OutputStream`, if that didn't help, the problem isn't in buffering.

Comment: @LaVloZMerrill You aren't making any sense. My comment is about flushing output steams that aren't buffered, and `InputStreamReader` (a) isn't an output stream, (b) doesn't have a `flush()` method, and (c) is buffered. It is therefore 100% irrelevant. Flushing a socket output stream does nothing, and that includes not calling a (non-existent) system call to do anything to the OS implementation. A `BufferedOutputStream` is buffered and therefore already covered in my comment. And the problem *isn't* in buffering. I've akready said that, and I per already answered the question.

Comment: @EJP its was just type error sorry for that, i wanted to say `OutputStreamWriter` (we can't flush incoming stream), `PipedOutputStream` also uses some buffers, you are talking in theorical way, but i'm talking in practical way, we all know that Java in some cases doesn't respect its Javadoc, another thing, i didn't read the OP's code, i saw him using OutputStream, so i wanted to mentions that maybe its a buffering issues and it was a comment, not answer ;)

Comment: @LaVloZMerrill `OutputStreamWriter` (a) is buffered and (b) isn't an output stream. It is therefore also 100% irrelevant. I am talking about what actually happens. You are just guessing. For example, there is no system call that flushes a TCP kernel socket send buffer.

Comment: @EJP i know that `OutputStreamWriter` isn't an `OutputStream`, but the same logic is applied to readers. Java supports many plateforms, i don't know if there is (or isn't) a system call that flushes a TCP kernel buffer on all supported plateforms.

Comment: @LaVloZMerrill It is difficult to have a rational discussion when you keep introducing extraneous or non-existent elements into it. Readers don't have `flush()` methods, and that's what we are discussing. Calling `flush()` on output streams that aren't buffered. Readers are irrelevant; buffered output streams are irrelevant; and, for clarity, buffered writers are also irrelevant. Also, for completeness, input streams, whether buffered or not. I *do* know that there isn't such a system call, and if you don't know that there *is* you shouldn't be making claims that rely on its existence.

Comment: @EJP do you believe me if i tell you i'm a little sick and i wanted to write writers but my hands wrote readers? what i think you didn't understand is i'm talking in general way, if you have a reference which contains an `OutputStream` that doesn't mean the object is exactly `OutputStream` but is compatible with `OutputStream` (we all know this), another thing, on socket objects there's the property TcpNoDelay, enable/disable it (Nagle's algorithm), if you enable it, output streams start to buffer according to Nagle's algorithm and output stream isn't buffered, but it buffers internally.

Comment: @LaVloZMerrill You made a simple statement: the OP should flush the output stream. I made a simple statement in contradiction: flushing an output stream that isn't buffered does nothing, and that includes socket output streams, as per the OP's code. Nothing you have said since then alters the truth of my statement; some of what you is imaginary; and the rest is irrelevant, including the Nagle algorithm. Your state of mind isn't relevant to the discussion.

Comment: @EJP that is, by your comments you are assuming that the output stream isn't buffered (by direct BufferedXXX or by internal buffers) without seeing it, but in my comments i was assuming that maybe the OP is falling under some buffer issues, the OP doesn't past all the code, i don't know what is written in not pasted sections.

Comment: @LaVloZMerrill I am not 'assuming' but  *explicitly stating* that calling `flush()` on the output stream of a socket does nothing, and ditto any other output stream that isn't buffered. The OP isn't using a `BufferedOutputStream` in any way shape or form. He is writing directly to the socket's output stream, and that is also up there in black and white. Please stick to the point.

Comment: @EJP that's not always true (maybe in this example is true), because `Socket` implementation is based on `SocketImpl`, anyone can write `SocketImplFactory` and passed to `Socket` class, then `Socket` class start using this factory to create `SocketImpl`, and by calling `Socket.getOutputStream` in reality it delegates to `SocketImpl.getOutputStream`, and here the stream can be a buffered stream, and `flush` can be overriden.

Comment: @LaVloZMerrill It is true of the OP's code, which is what the question is about. An implementation such as you describe would break most sockets code.

Comment: @EJP it wouldn't break anything if its correctly implemented, because Java already provide an implementation of this class and it doesn't break anything

Comment: @LaVloZMerrill An implementation of `Socket.getOutputStream()` where `flush()` wasn't a no-op would break existing code that assumed it was a no-op.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is **not** an 'efficiency issue'. It is a bug in your code.

> The problem is that not all of the messages are transferred to a server.

No, the problem is that you are losing data *at* the server. This is because you keep recreating `BufferedReaders`. You should create it once for the life of the socket.

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
```

Remove this line.

The way you have it, you will lose data every time the prior `BufferedReader` has, err, buffered.

You also need to close the socket.